# Needed clarity on CMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED property

Tags: cmake

Many of the open source projects include a set of directories with CMake's `SYSTEM` attribute. With this, these header files are provided to gcc with `-isystem` option:

```
include_directories(SYSTEM ${pybind11_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

The inclusion of C++ headers using `-isystem` has issues on AIX as gcc on AIX by default adds implicit `extern "C"` for headers included with `-isystem` option. This causes `templates in extern "C"` errors on AIX. (More details can be found at [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+bug/1698539))

So, was trying to see if we can use any CMake feature to have `-I` option used for these C++ headers, though these are included with `SYSTEM` option on AIX. Otherwise, we need to change a whole lot of `include_directories()` invocations in these projects for AIX alone.

I came across `CMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED` attribute which sets the default value of `NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED` for targets. But, setting it didn't override the `SYSTEM` attribute set in `include_directories()`.

Please let me know whether we are using `CMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED` rightly and if there is any other CMake option to achieve the above.

Comment: As you can see from the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/prop_tgt/NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED.html), property `NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED` affects only on *IMPORTED* targets: the libraries which are built **not** in your project. It seems that given property is not useful in your case.

Comment: (Both C++ and cmake are multiplatform; which means they are very hard to use on exotic platforms like AIX)